# Clear all text elements in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

someone has a solution for this.
I have a XML that is fully populated with test data. I need to clean out all the element text.

```
<xml>
    <parent>
        <child>A</child>
        <child>B</child>
        <pet>
            <dog>C</dog>
            <cat>D</cat>
        </pet>
    </parent>
</xml>
```

Needs to become

```
<xml>
    <parent>
        <child></child>
        <child></child>
        <pet>
            <dog></dog>
            <cat></cat>
        </pet>
    </parent>
</xml>
```

My real XML contains over 100 different element names, so I need a generic approach.

I'm trying variations of an identity transform but I'm getting XSL errors.

> Error in file:cleanxml.xsl
>   -2147467259 To create nodes of type 'ELEMENT', a valid name must be specified.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match='/|@*|node()'>
    <!--
    Regular Identity Transform
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
    </xsl:copy>
    -->
    <xsl:variable name='name' select='local-name()'/>

    <xsl:element name='{$name}'>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The reason for the failure message is that your template is matching nodes such as document nodes and text nodes, that have no name; so the value of $name is a zero-length string, and you can't create an element whose name is a zero-length string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with the identity transformation and then add

```
  <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]"/>
```

so with XSLT 3 (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMec) all you need is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or for earlier versions you need to spell out the identity transformation as

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

instead of using the `xsl:mode`.